# Notebook suspends only once

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management

My ASUS U38DT performs suspend (after closing lid or choosin option) only once after reboot.

Second time at the same session suspend doesn't happen.

```
Wed Apr  1 00:21:45 MSK 2015: performing suspend
This kernel doesn't have KMS support.
fbcon fb0 state 1
fbcon fb0 state 0
Wed Apr  1 14:06:35 MSK 2015: Awake.
Wed Apr  1 14:06:35 MSK 2015: Running hooks for resume
```

Before re-installation from 14.04 with 3.13 kernel everything worked fine.
Now I have clean installation 14.04.2 with 3.16 kernel I have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

0
down vote

have you solved this problem? I had exactly the same issue on my laptop when I installed Ubuntu 14.10

I tracked it down to a bug in the kernel, at least in my case. Try using my kernel see if it fixes it. Suspend has been working with no issues for me for about a week now so I'll push the change upstream when I have a chance.

http://lyktoree.com/dragan/linux-image-3.16.7-ckt8_3.16.7-ckt8-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb

md5sum: 568d6ff307bc646b4f69a64375bbc8f1 linux-image-3.16.7-ckt8_3.16.7-ckt8-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb

Built for x86_64, hope it helps.

Comment: No, I didn't. I just found that AMD proprietary GPU driver (fglrx) introduces the issue. 

The issue goes out when reverting back to open source xorg driver.

The bad news here is that open source driver can't switch off discrete GPU and therefore provides worse battery lifetime.

Comment: Now I am running Ubuntu 15.04 with the opensource AMD GPU driver. Suspend works.

Proprietary driver did not checked yet.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then my change wouldn't help you. Issue that affected my laptop was in the intel driver. Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: After struggling I installed the proprietary fglrx from Additional drivers tab.

Somehow eventually now suspend-wake_up procedure works as expected.

Possibly this caused the last kernel update, possibly this was fixed when I tried to install fglrx from AMD website and reverted to open xorg gpu driver.